# Unicode messages in oracle raise_application_error

Tags: java, oracle, unicode

I am working on ***enabling globalization support*** in my DB.
I have done migrating character set to UTF (AL16UTF16).
After migration, I can pass Unicode characters from Java to Oracle and store in table's NVARCHAR2 column. Also I can retrieve from DB and pass to Java.

But, If I do a **raise_application_error** with the Unicode data. It sends the error message to java like below

`; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20001: ¿¿¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿`

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? and how can I get the Unicode error messages in java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that the `NVARCHAR2` data type contains string in the _national character set_, which may  be different to the _database character set_. More concrete advice is difficult to provide without seeing code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @collapsar. The problem is the character set migration is not done properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I have done character set migration using the below steps, but it doesn't work for me.

1.Backup the database.
2.Run CSSCAN command.
3.Restart the DB with RESTRICT mode.
4.Run CSALTER script.
5.Restart the DB.

After that I have tried using the below steps.

1.Take backup of the DB using `expdp` command.
2.Create a new database with required character set (`Unicode AL32UTF8`).
3.Import the backup dump file into the newly created DB.

That's all. It works!

Now I don't need to use NVARCHAR2 data type to store unicode data (VARCHAR2 itself stores Unicode). **raise_application_error** also works fine (sends error messages with Unicode data to Java).

Thanks.